# How to design this the right way (and responsive!)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a [column](http://jsfiddle.net/7056ewyr/) in my Wordpress site with our country image and some text in it.

This is how it's supposed to look in a normal browser, and on a phone:

[image: how it's supposed to be]

Now, by default **Wordpress** doesn't parse this very well. If I only insert the text and the image in my column, it looks like this:

[image: default wordpress look]

As you can see, the column doesn't get it's required height. My solution is to add a div with a fixed height of 225px. **Then it looks good!** However, the **responsive** is not.

When I resize the window, it looks like this:

[image: responsive]

The image is not resized. The text is all over the place and the column has way too much height.

I have tried [this trick](http://wpbeaches.com/make-images-scale-responsive-web-design/) to make the image responsive, but that didn't work.

How can I design this the right way, so that it looks great on a normal sized screen and on a mobile?

```
<div class="fusion-one-half one_half fusion-layout-column fusion-column last spacing-yes"><div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:10px;">
<h2>VIND DE BEWINDVOERDER IN UW REGIO</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
consetetuer adipiscing elit.<br>
<img class="alignright size-full wp-image-78" src="http://zekerfz.icode4u.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ZEKERFZ_website_home_home_2_09.png" alt="landkaart" width="292" height="350">&nbsp;Aenean commodo ligula<br>
eget dolor. Aenean massa.<br>
Cum soccis natoque<br>
penatibus et agnis dis<br>
parturient montes, nasectur<br>
ridiculus mus.</p>
<div id="landkaart"></div>
</div></div>

#landkaart {
height: 200px;
}
#landkaart img {
max-width:100%;
}
```

See the jsFiddle for a replicate of my Wordpress column: http://jsfiddle.net/7056ewyr/

Comment: Dont set a height on your container. Your issue is you didnt clear your float. Additionally, the image is resizing when I'm resizing the window so your max widths is working. If you want the container of the image to size down you'll need to style the breakpoints.

Comment: Got it! I'm looking into the breakpoints now. Only part i don't understand is where to clear the float. What does clearing the float solve?

Comment: Whenever you float an item, it takes that item out of the flow of the document and attempts to wrap each proceeding element. After your containing element class="fusion-one-half one_half fusion-layout-column fusion-column last spacing-yes" add <div style="clear:both;"></div>. There are better ways to do this but this is a beginner/easy way